# Unable to install keras on Windows

Tags: python, keras, pip

This is the error while running my project source code:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Source Code\source code>python final.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Source Code\source code\final.py", line 10, in <module>
    from keras.models import Sequential
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Source Code\source code>pip3 install keras
Collecting keras
  Using cached keras-3.0.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.8 kB)
Collecting absl-py (from keras)
  Using cached absl_py-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.3 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from keras) (1.26.2)
Collecting rich (from keras)
  Using cached rich-13.7.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (18 kB)
Collecting namex (from keras)
  Using cached namex-0.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
Collecting h5py (from keras)
  Using cached h5py-3.10.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (2.5 kB)
Collecting dm-tree (from keras)
  Using cached dm-tree-0.1.8.tar.gz (35 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting markdown-it-py>=2.2.0 (from rich->keras)
  Using cached markdown_it_py-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.9 kB)
Collecting pygments<3.0.0,>=2.13.0 (from rich->keras)
  Using cached pygments-2.17.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.6 kB)
Collecting mdurl~=0.1 (from markdown-it-py>=2.2.0->rich->keras)
  Using cached mdurl-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (10.0 kB)
Using cached keras-3.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.0 MB)
Using cached absl_py-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (130 kB)  
Using cached h5py-3.10.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (2.7 MB)
Using cached rich-13.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (240 kB)
Using cached markdown_it_py-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (87 kB)
Using cached pygments-2.17.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: dm-tree
  Building wheel for dm-tree (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  × Building wheel for dm-tree (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [80 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tree
      copying tree\sequence.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tree
      copying tree\tree_benchmark.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tree
      copying tree\tree_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tree
      copying tree\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tree
      running build_ext
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 77, in _check_build_environment
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 408, in check_call
          retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
          with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
          hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-te7bosom\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 404, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-te7bosom\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 389, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-te7bosom\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-te7bosom\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 124, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-te7bosom\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-te7bosom\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-te7bosom\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-te7bosom\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-te7bosom\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-te7bosom\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-te7bosom\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 368, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-te7bosom\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-te7bosom\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-te7bosom\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-te7bosom\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 131, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-te7bosom\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-te7bosom\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-te7bosom\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "<string>", line 70, in run
        File "<string>", line 80, in _check_build_environment
      RuntimeError: CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: _tree
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dm-tree
Failed to build dm-tree
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dm-tree, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Source Code\source code>pip3 install keras
Collecting keras
  Using cached keras-3.0.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.8 kB)
Collecting absl-py (from keras)
  Using cached absl_py-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.3 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from keras) (1.26.2)
Collecting rich (from keras)
  Using cached rich-13.7.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (18 kB)
Collecting namex (from keras)
  Using cached namex-0.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
Collecting h5py (from keras)
  Using cached h5py-3.10.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (2.5 kB)
Collecting dm-tree (from keras)
  Using cached dm-tree-0.1.8.tar.gz (35 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting markdown-it-py>=2.2.0 (from rich->keras)
  Using cached markdown_it_py-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.9 kB)
Collecting pygments<3.0.0,>=2.13.0 (from rich->keras)
  Using cached pygments-2.17.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.6 kB)
Collecting mdurl~=0.1 (from markdown-it-py>=2.2.0->rich->keras)
  Using cached mdurl-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (10.0 kB)
Using cached keras-3.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.0 MB)
Using cached absl_py-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (130 kB)
Using cached h5py-3.10.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (2.7 MB)
Using cached rich-13.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (240 kB)
Using cached markdown_it_py-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (87 kB)
Using cached pygments-2.17.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: dm-tree
  Building wheel for dm-tree (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  × Building wheel for dm-tree (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [80 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tree
      copying tree\sequence.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tree
      copying tree\tree_benchmark.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tree
      copying tree\tree_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tree
      copying tree\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tree
      running build_ext
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 77, in _check_build_environment
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 408, in check_call
          retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
          with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
          hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uyuij33p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 404, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uyuij33p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 389, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uyuij33p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uyuij33p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 124, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uyuij33p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uyuij33p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uyuij33p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uyuij33p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uyuij33p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uyuij33p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uyuij33p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 368, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uyuij33p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uyuij33p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uyuij33p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uyuij33p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 131, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uyuij33p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uyuij33p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uyuij33p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "<string>", line 70, in run
        File "<string>", line 80, in _check_build_environment
      RuntimeError: CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: _tree
      [end of output]
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dm-tree
Failed to build dm-tree
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dm-tree, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Possibly relevant part of the error message: "*RuntimeError: CMake must be installed to build the following extensions:*"

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to install keras on your Windows PC but [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/keras/) states that:

> Keras 3 is compatible with Linux and MacOS systems. For Windows users, we recommend using Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2) to run Keras.

You might want to see [How to install Linux on Windows with WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install).